# six: cannot import name python_2_unicode_compatible

Tags: python, django, six

With `six 1.10.0` installed under Python and pip 2.6, an old Django 1.0.4 app is not able to import `python_2_unicode_compatible` even though it finds `six` 1.10.0 just fine:

```
>>> import six
>>> six.__version__
'1.10.0'
>>> from six import python_2_unicode_compatible
>>>
```

I've confirmed with python code within the app that it does indeed have access to `six`:

```
['appdirs==1.4.3', 'argparse==1.4.0', 'astkit==0.5.4', 'beautifulsoup==3.2.1',
'coverage==4.3.4', 'django-cms==2.0.0a0', 'django==1.0.4', 'dnspython==1.12.0',
'flup==1.0.2', 'importlib==1.0.4', 'iniparse==0.3.1', 'instrumental==0.5.3',
'mako==1.0.6', 'markupsafe==1.0', 'minimock==1.2.8', 'mysql-python==1.2.5',
'nose==1.3.7', 'packaging==16.8', 'pillow==3.4.2', 'pip==9.0.1', 'pluggy==0.4.0',
'py==1.4.33', 'pyparsing==2.2.0', 'python-dateutil==2.6.0', 'pyzor==1.0.0',
'setuptools==35.0.1', 'six==1.10.0', 'sorl-thumbnail==12.3', 'tox==2.7.0',
'uwsgi==2.0.15','virtualenv==15.1.0', 'wheel==0.29.0']
```

---

I am tasked to move a very old site that was running django 1.0.4 (you read that right, 1.0.4) and django_cms 2.0.0 Alpha to a new server.  The old server croaked, so all I have is the backup of the main website files and dependencies that were installed long ago.

I am Dockerizing it to help document and deploy this in the future.

```
Ubuntu 14.04
Python 2.6 (same results with 2.7)
Django 1.0.4 (installed via local zip)
django_cms 2.0.0a0 (installed via local zip)
```

I have tried `Apache mod_wsgi`, `gunicorn` (pip2.6 installed) and currently using `uwsgi` (preferred, pip2.6 installed) to load the app.

`Nginx` is running in another Docker container with `proxy_pass`, and will the frontend proxy and TLS.

`uwsgi` starts the site up with the custom `wsgi`.

Upon loading the `/` index page, I had many import errors.  Slowly, I am resolving each and every one of them (mostly related to the Django "MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES", which I have yet to find their definition).

I am currently stuck on the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 230, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 41, in load_middleware
    raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured, 'Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware cms.middleware.user: "cannot import name python_2_unicode_compatible"
```

uwsgi starts up with the specified python2.6 just fine:

```
web_1    | [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from uwsgi.ini
web_1    | *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.15 (64bit) on [Wed Apr 26 16:27:43 2017] ***
web_1    | Python version: 2.6.9 (default, Oct 22 2014, 19:53:49)  [GCC 4.8.2]
web_1    | Python main interpreter initialized at 0xef1050
web_1    | python threads support enabled
```

Also, python2.7 was originally configured and had the exact same error.  I thought I read where python_2_unicode_compatible was deprecated in 2.7 or something, so I went back to the original version the site was running under.

---

Do I need to install virtualenv?  I don't usually do it under Docker, and just install everything globally.  I can't see how that would make a difference.

If `six` was not found, wouldn't I get an error that it could not import six, instead of `python_2_unicode_compatible`?

Answer (score 3):

The `python_2_unicode_compatible` method was originally in Django, then added to `six` in 1.9.

One of your installed packages may be trying to import `python_2_unicode_compatible` from `django.utils.encoding`, rather than from the `six` package.

Comment: How in the hell did you see it trying to get it from `django.utils.encoding`? :)    anyhoot, not compatible?  humm.  i am not even sure it was using django_cms to begin with.  I just found a symlink in the old files that points to the installation that was local on the machine.  it's the only versions i found on the backups.

Comment: The traceback shows the error is in `cms.middleware.user`, so I [searched](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=python_2_unicode_compatible&type=) the django-cms repo for `python_2_unicode_compatible` :)

Comment: I just went through each of those files, and they either do not exist or are completely different versions than the `django_cms` I have installed locally. it looks like your search was in version 3.4.x - which is 8 years newer than the version I listed above (2.0.0a0).

Comment: You're right, the GitHub search is for the master branch. I still think that something might be trying to import `python_2_unicode_compatible` from `django.utils.encoding` rather than from `six`. I can't tell any more from the traceback though.

Comment: Many packages still do that, years later.  `pinax.notifications` for instance.

Comment: @MikeRobinson Importing from `django.utils.encoding` was OK for Django apps, it avoided having an extra dependency on `six`. The problem is that when you get to Django 3.0+, the `python_2_unicode_compatible` app has been removed. When an app adds support for Django 3.0, it can either drop support for Python 2 and remove `python_2_unicode_compatible` (Django 1.11 is about to go end of life anyway), or they can switch to using `six`.

Comment: Here's a [pull request for pinax notifications](https://github.com/pinax/pinax-notifications/pull/94) that adds support for Django 3.0 by dropping support for Python 2 and removing the import.